# Execute two functions for a button in flutter

Tags: flutter

So i want to be able to save the text from the textcontroller that user have keyed in into shared preferences However, i want to go to the next page too at the same time.

So:

1. Save the text in a shared preference
2. Go to next page

   ```
   final _text = TextEditingController();

   _nameSaver() async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       prefs.setString('my_string_key', _text.text);
     }

   FooterRaisedButton(
                     "Next",
                     () => (_text.text.isEmpty)
                         ? null
                         : Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/onboardMarket'),
                     "#0087a8")
   ```

I dont know how to call out the function that saves the name at the same time the button pressed will go to the next page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove fat arrow (`=>`), and implement it like this:

```
FooterRaisedButton(
  "Next",
   () async {
    if (_text.text.isEmpty)
      return; // return if it is empty
    await nameSaver(); // else save it here
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/onboardMarket'); // once done, navigate
  }
);
```

---

Just to give you a basic idea,

```
// only one statement can be executed using fat notation
RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _calculate(1));

// here you can perform as many as you need.
RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
  _calculate(1);
  _printScreen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it should work :

Code:

```
final _text = TextEditingController();

  _nameSaver() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('my_string_key', _text.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Next"),
        onPressed: (){
          if(_text.text.isEmpty){
            print("Cannot use empty text");
          }
          else {
            _nameSaver();
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/onboardMarket');
          }

        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I did the same thing, what's the difference?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad didn't see your code may be we were answering at the same time